# preg_match_all очистка от разных тегов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

В описании товаров магазина есть куча хтмл мусора.
Есть описания такого вида

```
<ul>
   <li><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Arial, serif; font-size: 12px; ">Кухонные весы</span></li>

   <li><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Arial, serif; font-size: 12px; ">Максимальный вес<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space: pre; ">    </span>5 кг</span></li>

   <li><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Arial, serif; font-size: 12px; ">Цена деления<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space: pre; ">    </span>50 г</span></li>

   <li><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Arial, serif; font-size: 12px; ">Вес брутто<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space: pre; ">    </span>0,6 кг</span></li>

   <li><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Arial, serif; font-size: 12px; ">Вес нетто<span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space: pre; ">    </span>0,34 кг</span></li>

   <li><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Arial, serif; font-size: 12px; ">Габариты короба (Д/Ш/Г) 74х18,8х18,8 см</span></li>

   <li><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Arial, serif; font-size: 12px; ">Характеристики кухонных весов</span></li>

   <li><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Arial, serif; font-size: 12px; ">Легко моющаяся съёмная чаша</span></li>

   <li><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Arial, serif; font-size: 12px; ">Ручная регулировка и установка нуля</span></li>
   </ul>
```

и такого вида

```
<div> 
<ul>
   <li>3 в 1: Блендер, Миксер, Измельчитель</li>

   <li>Погружной блендер из нержавеющей стали</li>

   <li>Венчики для взбивания яиц и крема</li>

   <li>Чаша измельчителя</li>

   <li>2 скоростных режима</li>

   <li>Настенный держатель</li>

   <li>Мерный стаканчик</li>

   <li>Мощность: 700 Вт</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

И это не все счастье которое мне достается.

Мне нужно очистить это описание от хтмл, сохранив строки, тоесть чтобы потом показать пользователю так:

- Кухонные весы Максимальный вес    5
- Цена деления    50 г
- Пункт списка
- Вес брутто  0,6 кг
- Пункт списка
- Пункт списка

Я делаю вот так: `preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",$mytext,$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`

Но спаны и т.д не очищаются. Помогите пожалуйста написать правильную регулярку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
$content = $arResult['DETAIL_TEXT'];
$content = explode('###', strip_tags(str_replace('<li>', '###', $content)));
// 1) заменяем все <li>(или любой другой 100% существующий тег)
// на ###(или любую отсутствующую последовательность символов);
// 2) делаем strip_tags (остается "test1###test2###test3");
// 3) разбиваем строку по разделителю ###

// окей, разбиваем по столбцам =)
foreach ($content as $n => $str)
  if (!trim($str))
    unset($content[$n]);
$out = array(array(), array());
$count2 = floor(count($content)/2);
$n = 0;
foreach ($content as $str) {
  $out[intval($n>$count2)][] = trim($str);
  $n++;
  }

// var_dump($out); // 0 - первый стоблец, 1 - второй.
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li><h4>Первый столбец</h4></li>';
foreach($out[0] as $str)
  echo '<li>'.$str.'</li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li><h4>Второй столбец</h4></li>';
foreach($out[1] as $str)
  echo '<li>'.$str.'</li>';
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Извините, я не сильно понял что оно делает. Оно подойдет для обоих случаев?

Comment: Не получаестся, почему-то.

Смотрите как я делаю сейчас, включая разбивание текста на столбцы.
preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",$arResult["DETAIL_TEXT"], $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$counti = count($out[1]);
$polovina = round($counti/2,0);
<здесь ul>
<?
for ($i=0; $i<$polovina; $i++) {
echo "<здесь li><span style=\"margin-left:-5px;\">".$out[1][$i]."</span></li>";
}
?>
</здесь ul>
<здесь ul>
<?
for ($i=$polovina; $i<$counti; $i++) {
echo "<здесь li><span style=\"margin-left:-5px;\">".$out[1][$i]."</span></li>";
}
?>
</здесь ul>

Comment: Почти получилось, все равно остался какой то знак. Но столбцы в любом случае получились не одинаковые.
http://polar.ru/new/?section=mini_treaters&product=plr_2024

в данном описании еще есть тег <р></р>

Битрикс вставляет кучу тегов когда используется визуальный редактор, надо все предусмотреть.

Comment: И еще раз)) Даже проверил: <a href="http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test/">скрипт</a> <a href="http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test/test.txt">хтмл</a> Если комментарий не пишется, удаляйте первый - лимит 3.

Comment: Sh4dow огромное спасибо :) Ты гениален) Прочитав о тебе на твоем сайте, ты гениален в двойне :)

Comment: Ответ примите лучше) А вообще спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно очистить строку от тегов, используйте [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). Можете "убить" все, кроме ul и li и показать.

Comment: Делал. Но стрип тэг бывает пожирает строки и убирает новую строку. А мне нужно сохранить столбец, чтобы потом сформировать из одного столбца - два.